# how to set activity page for only 5 days period after android app upgrade and login

Tags: java, android, date

I need to set release notes activity page for 5 days period of time only after I update my android application and first time login. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily ,you can store the installation time in shared preferences with the app version code(found in manifest) as key and Everytime when your app launches you fetch the time from preferences .
This will give you app update time.

Note :
 You will only update the key when it is not in preferences.
Each update will have a new key consist of latest version code.

Comment: I need to check first time login condition also after app update. Can you please guide me on this.

Comment: You can do this in similar way ,can save one more key after login. And key only be saved once for each version and hence it should consist of version code .